# Unable to Install PowerShell Package: snTeamsTest 0.1.2

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I am attempting to install a PowerShell package for Microsoft Teams (so I can write a script to assign users to channels), but I keep receiving the following error:

```
The module 'snTeamsTest' cannot be installed or updated because the authenticode signature of the file 'snTeamsTest.psd1' is not valid.
```

I have upgraded PowerShell to PowerShell7, but that did not work.
Google has completely failed me.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using PowerShell ISE to write the scripts, and in spite of upgrading to PowerShell7, Powershell ISE was not upgraded, and so I was unable to use the cmdlets that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the PowershellGallery page for snTeamsTest you see this text:

> The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the module
> is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.

So I'm guessing the module is unsafe or not developed anymore.

There is an official MS Teams Module that you can install with:

```
Install-Module MicrosoftTeams
```

Does that not have the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Unfortunately, I'm trying to use the cmdlet, Add-TeamChannelUser, which is still in beta.